# Deleting Row from Database C# WPF Linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to delete a row from the Database on a selected row in my Datagrid
I already got how to select a row in my Datagrid, but when I delete it on button_click it only deletes  it in my Datagrid but not in my actual Database

I'm using the following code to delete my Rows:

```
private void btnDeleteUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Do You Want to Delete this User?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            var query =
                from t in db.tbl_Users
                where t.Name == name
                select t;

            foreach (var t in query)
            {
                db.tbl_Users.DeleteOnSubmit(t);
            }

            db.SubmitChanges();

            var refresh =
                        (from q in db.tbl_Users
                         select new { Name = q.Name, Rights = q.Rights, Operatortag = q.Operatortag, Active = q.Active, Cardcode = q.CardCode }).ToList();

            dgUsers.ItemsSource = refresh;
        }
    }
```

My Database-property is set on Copy If Newer and I already tried to set in to Copy Always but that wouldn't help either.

Does someone know the answer to my problem?

Comment: 'Copy If Newer' is the correct choice, and please try run the application itself without the debugger/visual studio.

Comment: That doesn't work Either @LeiYang

Comment: If you step through and debug the code does "query" have a value or is it null?

Comment: Nope, it's filled @chillfire

Comment: Are you using a LinqDataAdapter to populate the datagrid?

Comment: I'm using LinqToSQLDataContext to retrieve data from the DB @chillfire

Comment: When the SubmitChanges is fired you should be able to view the SQL generated in the db context, this SQL can be run/validated against SQL server directly?

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more? @chillfire

Comment: The db context just generates SQL that is run against the DB, you can view this in one of the properties of the context before the submitchanges is processed. I cant remember the exact property. If you are using aspnet you can add http://miniprofiler.com/ to your project and see the SQL and many other helpful bits.

When you get the SQL you can run it directly on your database and see if there are errors or how many rows are changed etc

Comment: Do you mean by any chance "Copy to Output Directory"? @chillfire

Comment: No idea about that, I havent used that before for this. You can setup logging on the DbContext as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196585/how-can-you-see-the-sql-that-is-causing-an-error-on-submitchanges-in-linq-to-sql

But seeing what your DbContext is actually doing on your database can be helpful and miniprofiler is the easiest way to do it without changing any code/properties

Comment: I did what you said, but I don't see anything wrong. It works as it should (theoretically) but somewhere along the way between the Datacontext and the Database something goes wrong but what is still a mysterie

Comment: Can you connect to the database with the user in your connection string and run the DELETE SQL under that account?

Comment: Yes, I did @chillfire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call .ToList() hope it will help

```
var items = query.ToList();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    db.tbl_Users.DeleteOnSubmit(item);
}
```

or you can use *DataContext*

```
List<GroupMember> removeFromGroup = (from gm in dataContext.GroupMembers
                                 where (gm.memberID == memberid))
                                 select gm).ToList();

dataContext.GroupMembers.DeleteAllOnSubmit(removeFromGroup);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: could you please try this, first check if query is returning some value or not                    var items = query.ToList();                 db.tbl_Users.DeleteAllOnSubmit(items);
db.SubmitChanges();

Comment: already done that, it works as it should (theoretically) but somewhere along the way between the Datacontext and the Database something goes wrong

Comment: Could you plz try using DataContext to delete I just add in my original answer .. hope it will help .. or I will learn something new :)